# Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: `{userId: 1, email: email@yahoo.com, store: <app@store:main::ember370>}` does not appear to be an ember-data model

Tags: ember.js, model, ember-data

I have a User Model defined as an Object.Model

```
import Ember from "ember";

export default Ember.Object.extend({
  apiKey: null,
  userId: null,
  firstName: null,
  lastName: null,
  birthday: null,
  gender: null,
  city: null,
  state: null,
  email: null
});
```

I have a sign_up controller which makes an POST request to an API to register a new user. If the ajax post returns successfully, I want to create a new user instance with this line: `self.store.createRecord({userId: response["user"]["id"], email: response["user"]["email"]});`

In my router.js file, I have:

```
Router.UsersSignUpRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
 model: function() {
  return this.store.find('user');
 }
});
```

When the register POST returns, I get the error `Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: {userId: 1, email: email@yahoo.com, store: <app@store:main::ember370>} does not appear to be an ember-data model`

Comment: You need to specify the type of the record you are creating. Then you pass the object. e.g `self.store.createRecord('user',{userId: response["user"]["id"], email: response["user"]["email"]});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the model type as the first argument when calling `createRecord`, then you should be good to go.

```
self.store.createRecord('user', {userId: response["user"]["id"], email: response["user"]["email"]});
```

Here's the [documentation for `createRecord`](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_createRecord)